# Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 adapter not found on Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

After updating to 20.04.3 from a previous 20.04 version, my Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 adapter is not being detected.

- Laptop: Dell Precision 7760
- Dual boot with Windows 10, with fast boot/fast power-up switched off
- Kernel: `5.11.0-27-generic`

Output for `lshw -C network`:

```
    WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:94:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:b5200000-b5203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (14) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 11
       serial: 38:14:28:46:8a:89
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.11.0-27-generic duplex=full firmware=0.4-4 ip=192.168.1.245 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:149 memory:b5580000-b559ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Output for `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[    2.713748] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.727171] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.727199] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 93.8.63.28
[    2.727789] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.874389] Modules linked in: snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm_intel nvidia(PO+) libarc4 fjes(-) snd_rawmidi btusb dell_wmi(+) i915(+) kvm uvcvideo(+) dell_smbios dcdbas snd_seq btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel btintel videobuf2_memops snd_seq_device iwlwifi aesni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_timer bluetooth videobuf2_common crypto_simd videodev cryptd snd glue_helper input_leds ecdh_generic intel_cstate mc efi_pstore serio_raw dell_wmi_sysman(+) cfg80211 ecc dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof soundcore hid_multitouch(+) drm_kms_helper ee1004 mei_me cec processor_thermal_device processor_thermal_rfim rc_core i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_mbox cros_ec_ishtp processor_thermal_rapl intel_pmt_telemetry fb_sys_fops mei ucsi_acpi(+) cros_ec intel_pmt_class syscopyarea typec_ucsi sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_rapl_common typec intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad sparse_keymap acpi_tad
[    2.874974] Modules linked in: snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm_intel nvidia(PO+) libarc4 fjes(-) snd_rawmidi btusb dell_wmi(+) i915(+) kvm uvcvideo(+) dell_smbios dcdbas snd_seq btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel btintel videobuf2_memops snd_seq_device iwlwifi aesni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_timer bluetooth videobuf2_common crypto_simd videodev cryptd snd glue_helper input_leds ecdh_generic intel_cstate mc efi_pstore serio_raw dell_wmi_sysman(+) cfg80211 ecc dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof soundcore hid_multitouch(+) drm_kms_helper ee1004 mei_me cec processor_thermal_device processor_thermal_rfim rc_core i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_mbox cros_ec_ishtp processor_thermal_rapl intel_pmt_telemetry fb_sys_fops mei ucsi_acpi(+) cros_ec intel_pmt_class syscopyarea typec_ucsi sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_rapl_common typec intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad sparse_keymap acpi_tad
[    2.875674] Modules linked in: snd_pcm(+) snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm_intel nvidia(PO+) libarc4 fjes(-) snd_rawmidi btusb dell_wmi(+) i915(+) kvm uvcvideo(+) dell_smbios dcdbas snd_seq btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel btintel videobuf2_memops snd_seq_device iwlwifi aesni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_timer bluetooth videobuf2_common crypto_simd videodev cryptd snd glue_helper input_leds ecdh_generic intel_cstate mc efi_pstore serio_raw dell_wmi_sysman(+) cfg80211 ecc dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof soundcore hid_multitouch(+) drm_kms_helper ee1004 mei_me cec processor_thermal_device processor_thermal_rfim rc_core i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_mbox cros_ec_ishtp processor_thermal_rapl intel_pmt_telemetry fb_sys_fops mei ucsi_acpi(+) cros_ec intel_pmt_class syscopyarea typec_ucsi sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_rapl_common typec intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad sparse_keymap
[    2.876147] Modules linked in: snd_pcm snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event kvm_intel nvidia(PO+) libarc4 fjes(-) snd_rawmidi btusb dell_wmi(+) i915(+) kvm uvcvideo(+) dell_smbios dcdbas snd_seq btrtl videobuf2_vmalloc btbcm crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel btintel videobuf2_memops snd_seq_device iwlwifi aesni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 snd_timer bluetooth videobuf2_common crypto_simd videodev cryptd snd glue_helper input_leds ecdh_generic intel_cstate mc efi_pstore serio_raw dell_wmi_sysman(+) cfg80211 ecc dell_wmi_descriptor wmi_bmof soundcore hid_multitouch(+) drm_kms_helper ee1004 mei_me cec processor_thermal_device processor_thermal_rfim rc_core i2c_algo_bit processor_thermal_mbox cros_ec_ishtp processor_thermal_rapl intel_pmt_telemetry fb_sys_fops mei ucsi_acpi(+) cros_ec intel_pmt_class syscopyarea typec_ucsi sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_rapl_common typec intel_soc_dts_iosf mac_hid int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone int3400_thermal intel_hid acpi_thermal_rel acpi_pad sparse_keymap
[    2.888830] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    3.043713] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0xd35929d8
[    3.149838] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: Timeout waiting for PNVM load!
[    3.149843] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    3.149848] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: iwl_trans_send_cmd bad state = 1
[    3.353443] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: firmware didn't ACK the reset - continue anyway
[    3.365641] iwlwifi 0000:94:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

I have seen several similar questions on various forums but none of their solutions have worked here. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Search here on AU for AX210 and you'll find your answer.

Comment: Please see the duplicate. You have the same symptoms and require the same fix.